# remove the file from git but keep it locally in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

Using command line, I can use

```
git rm --cached $FILE_PATH
```

In intellij 2017, I can add a file to the git index with the context menu, but it does not have the option to remove but keep a file in the index.

Typing the command is painful as a lot of java files are buried in nested directories.

Comment: You can remove whole directories, you know, through `git rm --cached -r $FILE_DIR`...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are no plans to add such a feature, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-107359

Moreover, IntelliJ cannot commit such a change, cause it calls `git commit --only` - see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-138847